# Run program once at first logon (Windows 10 sysprep)

Tags: windows-10, sysprep

I'm setting up a custom Windows 10 image, and I have a program that I need to run only once after I log in for the first time.

I'm using sysprep, and I tried calling up the program using SetupComplete.cmd, but that won't work: the program needs to run interactively (within a user account). Doing it with SetupComplete.cmd, it doesn't launch.

My unattend.xml creates the user account automatically and all of the OOBE is skipped. After that's finished, I get the logon screen.

Regarding the RunOnce registry keys: I've read plenty on what they are and how they work, but I can't find any information on **how to specifically set them up**.

My program is called up by running `program.exe -flag -"flag:variable" -"flag:variable"`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Tried RunOnce registry location? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Should have mentioned that in the question sorry. I've found lots of documentation on the RunOnce key that explains how it works and what it does, but can't seem to find any documentation on *how to set it up*. Edit: added to question.

Comment: According to that source it is just `description-string=commandline` so for you would be `something=program.exe -flag -"flag:variable" -"flag:variable"` and that's all.